# Exporting Data from Access Database into .csv File

Tags: database, csv, ms-access

My company is planning to migrate from our current database (MS Access) to a new one. I'm being asked by our consulting firm to provide them with a .csv file containing all of the existing data. My question is... is there a way to export all of the existing data from an Access database into a single .csv file? We're currently running MS Office 2007, if that matters.

Any guidance you can offer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Best regards,

John

Answer (score 1):

Of course no. You can export to 1 csv **per table**.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a .CSV file is that all columns contain the same type of information, and the header (optionally) contains the title of the column. So in this concept you can not share multiple tables.

You could concat all the files into one, but no other application would be able to read your construct.

You can however transport a collection of .csv files in one .zip file if you like. Or you can export all tables (one tab per table) in an MS-Excel file.